What is the general theory behind finding similar sequences of symbols, such as for rhyming multiple syllables?
I am considering how to create a rhyming dictionary, provided I have a database of phonetic representations of words, and about 1 million words phonetically transcribed.
Sidenote: I also have phonetic features mapped to decimal numbers and such similar to this ALINE algorithm, so I can represent phonetic features (of consonants and vowels) using decimal numbers between 0 and 1.
Rhyming seems to be a sort of sequence alignment problem. I have heard the term "sequence alignment" in the context of bioinformatics for finding similar genetic code sequences, but that's as much as I know. Rhyming seems slightly different from genetic code sequence similarity finding, because with genes, you might have gaps in between which you can ignore, to find patches which could have had large things inserted in between them. With rhyming, you want I guess each syllable to have a weight, but then the whole flow to be aligned somehow.
So for this question, how does the general theory work for matching sequences of rhyming syllables? Assume we have calculated the similarity/weight between each independent sound. Then we have sequences of sounds, which form a syllable. And sequences of syllables. So I'm wondering where I can research further, knowing some of the basics of how this sort of nested sequence alignment might work.
